# Create Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Template link - https://github.com/MG-Microsoft/MLOps_Workshop/blob/main/environment_setup/iac-create-environment-pipeline-arm.yml

**I am creating an azure pipeline using above template but got this error.**

Deployment name is cloud-environment-20211115-065948-798a

There were errors in your deployment. Error code: DeploymentFailed.

##[error]At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.

##[error]Details:

##[error]BadRequest: Storage Account update is not supported yet

##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting

##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.

Comment: Could you please refer this MS DOC-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/ci-cd-github-troubleshoot-guide#updating-property-type-is-not-supported

Comment: Nothing is mentioned related to this error

Comment: Could you please open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues)  for this same.